# rstudio server on gnuroot (pixel c, android)

Tags: android, authentication, rstudio-server

I tried to install rstudio server on my pixel c within `gnuroot` which is based on a Debian linux (wheezy)

I compiled and started rstudio server, tried to log in on `localhost:8787` but it fails with:

```
rstudio initialization error
error occured during transmission
```

I verified the installation by running

```
  sudo rstudio-server verify-installation
```

and it gave me the following error message:

```
26 Apr 2016 21:51:44 [rserver] ERROR system error 98 (Address already in use); 
OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::http::initTcpIpAcceptor(rstudio::core::http::SocketAcceptorService<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, const string&, const string&)
 /tmp/rstudio-rstudio-5dbc604/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/TcpIpSocketUtils.hpp:103;
 LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /tmp/rstudio-rstudio-5dbc604/src/cpp/server/ServerMain.cpp:438
```

Any idea what's wrong here?